# How do I get img to align at flex-end?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to react so when I tried aligning my image the CSS way it failed. The only way I can get the image to align to the right side of the screen is by positioning it. Any alternatives?

I tried doing jjustifyContent ,justifySelf and even floating to right. Nothing works.

[Image to my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njC4P.png)

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  main: {
display: "flex",
justifyContent: "flex-end"
},
header: {
color: "white"
},img: {
justifySelf: "flex-end"
 }});

export default function Header() {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
<div className={classes.main}>
  <span className={classes.header}>Header</span>

  <img
    className={classes.img}
    src="https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png"
  />
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: This isn't really reactjs, it's more CSS.

Comment: CSS flexbox works fine. It is in react that flexbox starts behaving abnormally

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, `justify-content: space-between`

Your style should be,

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  main: {
   display: "flex",
   justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  header: {
   color: "white"
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work with two images. I have actually two images I want adjusted to right. First justifyContent didn't work an then I tried adjusting width in main, It worked but with two images One image gets centered. I tried justifySelf in img and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Please check above answer. you just have to make image left margin to auto.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div style="width: 50%;">
      <img width="20%" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHGbRmrMlg4j7xLGAEp1GLJ-oeq3-1C7rkXPm8uhu5cq1vx1n8" alt="">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%;">
      <img width="20%" style="float: right;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHGbRmrMlg4j7xLGAEp1GLJ-oeq3-1C7rkXPm8uhu5cq1vx1n8" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Try this if that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
you just have to make image `margin-left:auto;` please check attached example.
```

```css
.main{
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
span{
  color: #fff;
}
img{
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span class="header">Header</span>

  <img
    class="main-image"
    src="https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png"
  />
</div>
```